# Docker: Setting up dns for containers

Tags: docker, dns

I'm setting up a DNS (also in a container) for other containers. It works very well when I do it by hand (passing `--dns=172.17.0.100` to `docker run`).

But I need to use docker compose for my project, I cannot do it because the IP address of my DNS container changes all the time. I do not want to set static IP addresses for containers. How should I do this?

Is there a way that I can just pass the DNS container name and it recognize?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not really an answer but a few observations, too big for a comment ...

1 - you can retrieve information about a running container if that helps

```
docker inspect
```

2 - you can use environment variables in a docker-compose.yml file - these env vars could reference the IPs you want to use. You can also pass variable values to docker-compose.yml in a script.

Hopefully this will go part way to helping you solve this

Answer (score 0):

You can use linked containers with a custom entrypoint script. Start your container like this:

```
docker run --link your-dns-server:dns --entrypoint /path/to/entrypoint.sh <image> <command>
```

Alternatively, add the `ENTRYPOINT` to your image's `Dockerfile` instead of passing the `--entrypoint` parameter.

You can then write the nameserver to use to the `/etc/resolv.conf` file dynamically in the `entrypoint.sh` script (needs to be present in the container image):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "nameserver ${DNS_PORT_53_UDP_ADDR}" > /etc/resolv.conf
exec $@
```